# aligning to div's next to each other - media query

Tags: css, html

I am trying to render a section of my pafe as in this following image. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx93k.jpg> I can now get it to render right in larger screens. But when I use meduia query the second box mis aligns. I appears to be a little above first box. Is there way I can fix it?

```
<section class="carousel price-carousel">   <!--Price section -->
   <div class="container">

      <div class="price-container">
            <span class="month-column">
                    <h4>Monthly</h4>
                    <p>$9.95</p>
                    <p class=”sub-text”>per computer</p>
            </span>
             <span class="year-column"> 

                    <h4>Yearly</h4>
                    <p>$99</p>
                    <p class=”sub-text”>Save 20% when you pay anually</p>
              </span>
      </div>
</div>  
</section>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/d4gyo5s8/7/

Comment: Do you need media queries for this?  It seems like all you need is to place either a `margin-top` or `margin-bottom` on both.

Comment: Since you're using limited `width`s (30%) it is breaking the line of text, and miss aligning the layout...

Comment: well, I am using media queries to build responsive page. The problem I mentioned arises when I plug in a media query. I could very well be a margin issue but I wasn't able to figure out. I tried setting top margins to both month-column and year-column. None of what I did worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete:

```
margin-top:35px;
```

of set it to 0, in your media-query.

Also add:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Proof:
http://jsfiddle.net/zmqoz7pv/1/

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample, check the below code and the fiddle sample!!

**The HTML:**

```
<section class="carousel price-carousel">        
    <div class="container">
        <div class="price-container">
            <span class="month-column">
                <h2>Monthly</h2>
                <h3>$9.95</h3>
                <p class="sub-text">per computer</p>
             </span>
             <span class="year-column">            
                 <h2>Yearly</h2>
                 <h3>$99</h3>
                 <p class="sub-text highlight">Save 20% when you pay anually</p>
             </span>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**The CSS**

```
*, ht, h2, h3, h4, p, div, img {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.price-container {
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:top;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#333333;
}
.price-container span {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border:1px solid #676767;
    width:300px;
    background:#fafafa;
}
.price-container h2 {
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#f1f1f1;
    background:#676767;
    padding:5px 0;
}
.price-container h3 {
    font-family:'Arial Black', Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#000000;
    padding:8px 0;
}
.sub-text {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:16px;
}
.highlight {
    color:#609347;
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/exfjfzbo/6/)